# Can't keep the $rootScope value after refresh

Tags: angularjs

I'm new to angularJS and working over an application where i switch over multiple languages.
After i change the language and refresh the page it will switch to the default language (i.e)English.
Please suggest how do i keep the value of $rootScope so that it will not change after refreshing the page

My CTRL---------

myApp.controller('recordCtrl',function($scope, $translate, $http,altaMdlSvcs,$rootScope,$cookieStore,altaPageActionSvcs,$location,$rootScope,$stateParams) {
    $scope.globalLang = '';

```
$http.get("metadata/record.json").then(function(response) {
    $scope.recordArray = response.data.records;
});
$http.get("metadata/language.json").then(function(response) {
    $rootScope.languages = response.data;
});


var locale = localStorage.getItem("token");
//$translate.use(locale);


$scope.changeLanguage = function (langObj) {
    $scope.globalLang = langObj.lang.langCode;
    localStorage.setItem("token", $scope.globalLang);
    console.log("lower"+$scope.globalLang+"................");
    $translate.use(langObj.lang.langCode);
};
$scope.openModel = function(langObj) {
    var requestMap = {
            "templateHtml" : '/I18nDemo/html/model.html',
            "controllerName" : 'modelCtrl',
            "doAction" : $scope.changeLanguage,
            "lang" : langObj,
            "parent" : $scope
    };
    altaMdlSvcs.customOpen(requestMap);
};
```

});

Comment: Use browser cookie or session to save information

Answer (score 1):

By refreshing the page (f5) you will wipe your $rootscope from memory. Your application restarts.

As mentioned above you should probably use some kind of storage. That way you can save a users preference and use it again when he comes back to you application.

Have a look at: https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-storage